# LinkedIn Marketing API Creative names

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the marketing developer platform api to pull reports for my campaigns.

I want to be able to break down my reports by campaign and then by creative name.

In the LinkedIn documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#statistics-finder) they give examples of the statistics finder and say that it can pull up to 3 pivots.

This is the example they give:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=statistics&pivots[0]=CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.year=2017&timeGranularity=DAILY&campaigns[0]=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234567
```

I can't seem to get it to work for more than 1 pivot.

Another issue that I am facing is that I am not sure how to pull creative names - I can only seem to get creative ids in my api calls.

I am using the examples from to get campaign name:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/adcampaigns?context=linkedin/marketing/context

Looking at the creative name equivalent:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/adcreatives?context=linkedin/marketing/context
I cannot seem to find name for creatives here. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I too have the same problem.  Is this just a bad API design?  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I tried using the adCreativesV2 command to get more detail about a specific creative and it didn't return a useful name.

Answer (score 1):

The magic sequence to get multiple pivots is:

...q=statistics&pivots[0]=ACCOUNT&pivots[1]=CAMPAIGN&pivots[2]=CREATIVE&...

As for creative names, they do not 'simply' exist. There are different fields (variables/data) for each type of creative, and what you would see in the UI depends on the type of campaign/creative displayed. For a simple Text Ad, it would be variables.data.title and variables.data.text. For the rest, you need to use projection to get specific fields from the urn's referenced.

Comment: Pivoting on CREATIVE and expanding fully the pivot value does not return anything remotely useful to identify a urn with a readable advert name. It's so frustrating they are just showing that name on the AdsManager UI, but it is actually impossible to get it from their API. Typical Microsoft I'd say.

Comment: Send a support request to LinkedIn Developer Support and ask for the "LinkedIn Creatives API cheatsheet" spreadsheet file. I am not sure why they don't post it somewhere -- it has all of the creative name/description variations along with the API calls to pull the various components.